# SQL Data Reader: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am trying to use a `SqlDataReader` to run a query and then display the results in a messagebox, but I keep getting the error

> *Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.*

Here is my code.

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string results = "";
    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=100-nurex-x-001.acds.net;Database=Report;User Id=reports;Password=mypassword"))
    {
         cs.Open();
         string query = "select stationipaddress from station where stationname = @name";
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
         {
              // Add the parameter and set its value -- 
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
              using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                   while (dr.Read())
                   {
                        label3.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
                        results = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        //MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                        //MessageBox.Show(results);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(results);
              }
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just an insight : your query text doesn't need any formatting. In other words, you don't need to pass the text to string.Format(). You could have assigned it simply like this : string query = @"select top 1 stationipaddress from station".

Comment: If your `SELECT` doesn't return any data, then your call to `while (dr.Read())` will terminate immediately (there's nothing to read!), but two lines later, you still access `MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());` and **that's** going to fail miserably... Why is this line **outside** the `while (dr.Read())` block?? You should read the value into a string variable **inside** the block and then use it for the message box....

Comment: Just an insight : your use of string.Format() indicates that you may be accustomed to using it to substitute parameter data into a query. **THAT IS HORRIBLY INSECURE!** It leads to Sql Injection vulnerabilities. You need to use parameterized queries instead. Learn about them. Use them. If you already know about that and I'm reading too much into this, please disregard, but otherwise understand that this is _hugely_ important.

Comment: I think you updated your question with the solution so it's hard to tell what you were doing wrong.  In case someone else happens to have the same problem, they will not be able to identify it.  I would recommend not updating the code in the question with the solution.  Kind of defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 6):

That's correct.
When you exit from the while loop the DataReader has reached the end of the loaded data and thus cannot be used to get the value of a non-existant current record.

The Read method advances the SqlDataReader (dr) to the next record and it returns true if there are more rows, otherwise false.

If you have only one record you could use the `results` variable in this way

```
MessageBox.Show(results);
```

Now, this will work because you have a TOP 1 in your sql statement, but, if you have more than one record, it will show only the value of the last record.

Also as noted by marc_s in its comment, if your table is empty, your code doesn't fall inside the while loop, so probably you could initialize the results variable with a message like:

```
 results = "No data found";
```

EDIT: Seeing your comment below then you should change your code in this way

```
.....
// Use parameters **ALWAYS** -- **NEVER** cancatenate/substitute strings 
string query = "select stationipaddress from station where stationname = @name";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
{
    // Add the parameter and set its value -- 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            label3.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
            results = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }
}
.....
```

Comment: Ok, I understand I have to put it inside the while loop! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am also trying to use a textbox to get the stationname, but it doesn't seem to work. here is my query

Comment: string query = string.Format(@"select stationipaddress from station where stationname = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", textBox1.Text);

Comment: Please add this code to your original question clicking the edit button

Comment: Its still doesn't seem to be working correctly - Edited code above

Comment: Probably you don't have any record that corresponds to the value typed in textBox1.

Comment: @Steve- Then shouldn't the messagebox display as empty?

Comment: @Steve-Whenever I replace "@name" with the pc name it works fine

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue trying to get a GUID I knew was there - I could run the same SQL directly in SQL Management Studio and get my result.  So instead of trying to bring it back as a GUID (it was saved in a char(35) field, even though it really was a GUID!), I brought it back as a string, instead:

```
        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
        string projId = String.Empty;
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE project_name='My Project'";

        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConn);
            sqlConn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    projId = reader.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();   // <-- safest way I found to get the first column's parameter -- increment the index if it is another column in your result
                }                    
            }
            reader.Close();
            sqlConn.Close();
            return projId;                
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {                
            // handle error
            return projId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle error
            return projId;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
```