# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using C# to learn ASP.NET, I tried to write authentication code as

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [ID] from [Inspector] WHERE [ID] ='111' AND [Password] ='111';", conn);

SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

if (dr[0].ToString() == username)
{
Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
Session.Timeout = 1;
Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
}
else{
// ...
}
```

The `ID` is of type `numeric` in SQL Server.

The issue is I always get exception:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

In this part: `if (dr[0].ToString() == username)`.

I tried to execute the exact SQL statement directly and I can get the result.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: @SLaks I know that, but this is just learning code.

Comment: That's cool but might as well learn about password hashing http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635366/sql-data-reader-invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the reader's rows returned - using code something like this:

```
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.Read())
{
    if (dr[0].ToString() == username)
    {
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
    }
    else {
       // ...
    }
}
```

You need to call `.Read()` on the `SqlDataReader` at least once to actually **read** the data.

If you plan to read as many rows as there are, you should use

```
while (dr.Read())
{
     .....
}
```

and deal with the multiple rows being returned.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the DataReader to the first row before you can start reading data.
Call `Read()`.